# Where is the IdP Initiated URL for Connected Apps?

Tags: single-sign-on, connected-apps, winter14

Since Winter 14, Service Providers can no longer be added via the Identity Provider page. We need to add them under Connected Apps.

Till Summer 13, we could get the IdP Initiated URL from the Service Provider setting (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=identity_provider_examples.htm&language=th#sf_2_sf_example_gen_idp).

[image: till Summer 13]

However, this is not visible after the move to using Connected Apps.

[image: Connected Apps settings]

Where do I get it? The help document has not been updated either and there's no info in the release notes AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

This is available under Setup | Manage Apps | Connected Apps.

[image]